# How can I get SSH hosts of gears (uid@host) in Openshift scalable app?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I know about the command that I should use from my machine:

`rhc app show |app name| --gears`

I need the same command of any other way to know SSH hosts from any gear. There is possibility for main gear:

`cat ~/haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg`

and look at the last rows.

But there is no way to do that from other gears.

Could anybody help with it?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a command that will give you that information, the best way to get it is in the main gear in your haproxy.cfg that you already found.